# How to send variable from JS to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Althought I sent value and using method POST but when I call method POST it's not value

```
$("select#fieldCity").change(function() {
  var id = $("select#fieldCity option:selected").attr("value") ?
    $("select#fieldCity option:selected").attr("value") : 0;
  console.log(id);
  $.ajax({
    url: '../<?php echo $role; ?>/create',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      city_id: id
    },
  });
});
```

I call method POST to get value

```
$city_id = $_POST['city_id'] ? $_POST['city_id'] : 0;
```

Comment: *but when I call method POST it's not value*, so what is it?

Comment: can u `var_dump($city_id)` and show us ?

Comment: It have error "Undefined index"

Comment: It's not exist $_POST['city_id']

Comment: `$city_id = isset($_POST['city_id']) ? $_POST['city_id'] : 0;` should work like a charm :)

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat Not really because `id` always contains value `var id = $("select#fieldCity option:selected").attr("value") ?
    $("select#fieldCity option:selected").attr("value") : 0;`

Comment: @MinhDuc That does not make any sense. Ternary is there just to avoid empty values. You may try `console.log("" ? 1 : 0);`, followed by `console.log("a" ? 1 : 0);` to verify it by yourself

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat Yes, u r right. Good to know it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected value by just using `$(this).val()` instead of using `attr('value')`. Below is the updated JS code:

```
$("select#fieldCity").change(function() {
  var selectedCity = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '../<?php echo $role; ?>/create',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      city_id: selectedCity
    },
  });
});
```

And in your PHP, you can:

```
$city_id = isset($_POST['city_id']) ? $_POST['city_id'] : 0;
```